# Is jquery-ajax-unobtrusive part of .Net Core

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core, unobtrusive-ajax

I would like to use jquery-ajax-unobtrusive.js. But I have read on the following page https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/ajax/unobtrusive-ajax.  That "it is now part of ASP.NET Core and is hosted at GitHub".

The Github repo declares that the project is in maintenance mode.

I tried to contact the author Mike Brind but can't find a contact address and you need to be a premium LinkedIn member to send him a message. My question is.

What does a *part of .NET Core* mean?

It doesn't work unless I include a link to the js file itself.

Can I assume that he does not mean that the library is a part of .NET Core but that the helpers are?

Even so. If it is now in maintenance mode is it sensible to use it at all? Will it die or be replaced by something else?

Comment: `If it is now in maintenance mode is it sensible to use it at all? Will it die or be replaced by something else?`About this,you can create a new issue at [Github](https://github.com/aspnet/jquery-ajax-unobtrusive/issues).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What does a part of .NET Core mean?

[image]

In the picture,you can find the author is Microsoft,and .Net Core can support jquery-ajax-unobtrusive,so this may be why it is a part of .NET Core.

And then a default .net core project only includes the required js and css.Only when using `data-ajax-{}`,jquery-ajax-unobtrusive.js is needed.So it is not included in the default .net core project.

Comment: If it is helpful,can you mark it as answer?Thank you.